# Weighted sum of ratio of partial sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, co.combinatorics, asymptotics

I would like to approximate the following sum when $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $n \gg k$,

$\sum_{x = k}^n \sum_{y > x}^n \frac{\sum_{m = 0}^{k - 1} {y - 2 \choose m}}{\sum_{m = 0}^k {y - 1 \choose m}}$.

The catch is that there is no closed form for partial sum of binomial coefficients. I wonder if there is a good way to approximate $\frac{\sum_{m = 0}^{k - 1} {y - 2 \choose m}}{\sum_{m = 0}^k {y - 1 \choose m}}$ so that the approximation converges to a value given that $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $n \gg k$. Any help is greatly appreciate.

Revision:

I re-thought about my original problem, I believe solving the following problem would make more sense. However it is still unclear to me how to approximate the formula.

[Summing ratio of ratio of partial sums of binomial coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129931/summing-ratio-of-ratio-of-partial-sums-of-binomial-coefficients)

Comment: In your double sum, call the numerator of your expression s, which is short for s(y,k).  Now the denominator is 2s + (y-1) choose k, which I will write as 2s + t.
Note that for y > 3k, t>4s,  and one can make the difference between t and s more precise.   After one estimates the terms for y at most 3k, one is left with a double sum which will look like a sum of logs.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.05.06

Comment: It looks like the OP has posted a revised version as a new question, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129931/summing-ratio-of-ratio-of-partial-sums-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: (Note, the OP's new question doesn't have a sum over $x$, but the double sum here over $x$ and $y$ easily simplifies to a single sum over $y$.)

Comment: Yes I've wanted to revise this question to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129931/summing-ratio-of-ratio-of-partial-sums-of-binomial-coefficients. Sorry about taking up the spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summing ratio of ratio of partial sums of binomial coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129931/summing-ratio-of-ratio-of-partial-sums-of-binomial-coefficients)